# Value stored to `item` during its initialization is never read in range base loop

Tags: c++, c++17, clang-tidy

I am trying to fix analyzer errors, but I am stuck at this error, have no idea why I am getting this error here is my code.

```
struct Config{
  std::shared_ptr<std::set<int>> data;
  std::shared_ptr<std::set<int>> getData(){
     return data;
  }
}

void Engine::Notify()
{
    if(allowed)
    {
        for (auto item: *config.getData())
        {
            process->dispatch(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Error:
`Value stored to 'item' during its initialization is never read`

Comment: On an unrelated note, pointers to standard containers are almost never needed.

Comment: That sounds more like a warning. What does `process->dispatch()` do?

Comment: yeah, but its already there in the project. and I have to fix linter errors.

Comment: @scohe001 its sents notification.

Comment: but `dispatch` takes by value, can it be because of that?

Comment: Probably.  If `dispatch` takes by value, then the copy you made in the for loop is unneeded and is a performance loss.

Comment: Consider `const auto & item`.

Comment: looping by reference its worked fine.

Comment: Please post code for `dispatch`.

Comment: Assuming `dispatch(shared_ptr<...> &value)` it is possible that `dispatch` modifies but does not read `item`?